# Avoiding circular dependencies

Tags: javascript, typescript, circular-dependency

I have 2 classes like so.

```
export class Risk {
  ... other properties

  mitigations?: Mitigation[] = [];
}
```

and

```
export class Mitigation {
  ... other properties

  risks?: Risk[] = [];
}
```

I understand we should never do this, as this is circular dependency. The problem is, this is the reality. We're using neo4j, and can get back `Risk` with `Mitigations`, or a `Mitigation` with `Risks`.

How do I approach this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interfaces instead of a class. Interfaces don't have implementation details, so there's no risk of creating a circular dependency between two interfaces:

```js
export interface IRisk {
  // other properties
  mitigations?: IMitigation[]
}

export interface IMitigation {
  // other properties
  risks?: IRisk[]
}
```

Then, in your implementation files (e.g. risk.ts and mitigation.ts), you can implement the interfaces like this:

```js
// risk.ts
import { IRisk, IMitigation } from './interfaces'

export class Risk implements IRisk {
  // implementation details

  mitigations?: IMitigation[] = []
}

// mitigation.ts
import { IRisk, IMitigation } from './interfaces'

export class Mitigation implements IMitigation {
  // implementation details

  risks?: IRisk[] = []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*"I understand we should never do this, as this is circular dependency"*

No, such arrangement can be described as [mutually recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion). It's a very powerful technique and completely valid in typescript -

```
type Actor = {
    name: string,
    movies: Array<Movie>
}

type Movie = {
    title: string,
    actors: Array<Actor>
}
```

```
type Branch<T> = {
    data: T,
    children: Tree<T>
}

type Tree<T> = Array<Branch<T>>
```

There are many such relationships that are mutually recursive. You shouldn't avoid them based on a narrow understanding that it's the same as a circular dependency.

Mutually recursive datum can be effectively processed using mutually recursive procedures. If you are interested, I have written [many posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20mutual%20recursion) on the topic.

Comment: interesting. Will take a look